# How do I move a node from one document to another in Java?

Tags: java, dom

I'm having trouble with moving a node from one document to another one. I've used both the adoptNode and importNode methods from Node but they don't work as expected

```
Element element1 = document1.createElement("element1");
        Element root = document2.createElement("root");
        root.appendChild(element1);
```

expectation that is child of Element root is element1, that mean have the same HashCode or

```
root.getChildNodes().item(0) == element1;
```

return true

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at `importNode` :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean)

Comment: @Berger, thanks for reply but The imported node is a copy of the original.